# How Do I show diff changes from the Github PR view in my local unstaged changes?

Tags: git, github, terminal

When I'm working on a PR, I often like to unstage all changes I've ever made in the branch, so I can see every file modified in a diff view locally.

For example, I have a PR in Github to merge `foo-branch` into `origin/master`

I know I can use `git reset origin/master` to move all changes from `origin/master` into my unstaged changes, but the staged changes will include files that have changed upstream, but I've not yet merged into `foo-branch` using `git merge origin/master`.

I don't want to have to constantly keep merging `origin/master` into `foo-branch` to get accurate changes showing up via `git reset origin/master`, and Github seems to handle this fine, and only show me relevant files in the diff tab.

How can I use `git reset` to only unstage relevant files?

My desired workflow looks like this:

- make some changes, push to a branch `foo-branch`
- open a PR against `master` in Github
- some changes were requested, so then I move all my changes into unstaged via `git reset origin/develop`
- make changes, then do `git reset origin/foo-branch` to get **only my changes since my last commit on the branch**
- `git commit ...` and `git push origin HEAD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Github is showing you is the diff against your branch's `merge-base`, i.e. the most recent commit that is in `master` that is a parent of your branch `HEAD`. See the [manpage on `merge-base` here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)

You'd use:

```sh
git reset $(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)
```